# Verificar input dentro de slot VueJs

Tags: vue.js

Tengo un componente para el registro de usuarios que hace toda la verificación que se completaro los campos y demas que es el  siguiente:

```
<template>
  <section class="register">
    <header-register></header-register>
    <form-wrapper :onSubmit="handleSubmitRegister">
      <slot name="domain"></slot>
      <input-username @isValid="handleUsernameValidity"></input-username>
      <input-email @isValid="handleEmailValidity"></input-email>
      <input-password :confirmPassword="true" @isValid="handlePasswordValidity"></input-password>
      <captcha :getGrecaptcha="getGrecaptcha"></captcha>
      <button class="register__button" type="submit" id="register-button">REGISTER</button>
      <p class="warning_text" v-if="isError">{{ errorMessage }}</p>
    </form-wrapper>
  </section>
</template>
```

y resulta que tengo una seccion de la aplicación donde necesito un campo mas, entonces lo agregue con slot de la siguiente forma:

```
<register-from>
        <div slot="domain" class="domain-wrapper">
            <input class="register__input domain-input" type="text" placeholder="domain.com" name="domain"
                   value="domain"/>
            <label for="domain" class="static-value">https://</label>
        </div>
    </register-from>
```

Mi problema esta, en como puedo hacer la verificación del campo que agregué con slot de que esta vacio o no cuando envie el formulario del componente padre?